# Can't open Catalyst with administrative privileges

Tags: ati, graphics, multiple-monitors, xubuntu

For some reason I can't open Catalyst with administrative privaleges on Xubuntu 11.10. The regular Catalyst Control Center works fine, but it doesn't allow me to make necessary changes to my multiple monitor configuration. Is there a way to open it through the terminal with a sudo command, or is there anything else I should be looking for?

I used the command the following command to open Catalyst with admin privilages:

```
sudo amdcccle
```

I get the same results with `gksu`.

It automatically configure my multiple monitors and placed one on top of the other, instead of side by side. It won't allow me to make any changes. Every time I try to hit the apply button, it closes without making any changes.

If I go to Display, in the Settings Manager, it doesn't give me the option to configure multiple desktops. However, the changes I make there do stick.

Comment: Don't use `Sudo` with GUI applications use `gksu`.And yes it's a bug with the Catalyst Control Center.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately, I have the same results with gksu.

Comment: Does the same happen if you use XFCE's Display properties?.

Comment: If I got to Display, in the Settings Manager, it doesn't give me the option to configure multiple desktops. However, the changes I make there do stick.

Comment: using `gksudo amdcccle` in the terminal works for me on Kubuntu. I have the same issue as the OP if I try any other method.

Comment: The only way I could get it to work was by installing Unity and changing it through the Unity windows manager. Then logging back into XFCE. I wonder how many people have this problem.

Comment: I was forced to abandon Xubuntu. I am now using LMDE Mint 13, and gksu amdcccle worked flawlessly with my Radion 7500 series. I followed [this](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/09/how-to-install-amd-catalyst-129-driver.html) tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by installing Unity and changing it through the Unity window manager. Then logging back into XFCE. I wonder how many people have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working (on Xubuntu 12.04) using

```
sudo -s
```

and then as root run

```
amdcccle
```

Configuring in the AMD Catalyst resulted in a proper configuration at the login screen.

To get it working after login I had to change settings through the "Settings editor"
 then unfold "display" find the display you have on the right, unfold "position" and as x-position enter the x-resolution of your left display. This moves the image of the right display to the right. Log out and in again to see the result.